# Battling to get SPWeb, Sharepoint 2010 Object Model. 

Tags: spweb

I have the following URL to a subsite : http://myServerName/subSiteName
I know the URL to the subsite upfront.

So far I'm trying this, but it won't work.

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(this.siteURL))
{
  using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb(this.siteURL))
    {

    }
}
```

Any ideas why not? And what I'm doing wrong?

SPSite loads fine, but not SPWeb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's it :)
Works event with List-URLs to open a list (remove the "/AllItems.aspx")!

BTW: You don't have to Dispose SPWeb as long as you Dispose the SPSite object it came from.
So in your case

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(this.siteURL))
{
  SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb();
  SPList list = spWeb.GetList(this.siteURL);
  [...]
}
```

...would be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easier to solve than I thought it would be.

```
using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
```

This opens the URL of the site in the SPSite constructor.